# Discriminant of a number field in terms of variable

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, discriminant

I want to determine the discriminant of the number field generated by the polynomial
$$x^8-24tx^4+36t^2$$
in terms of the variable $t$, a square-free integer. Is this possible?

Comment: I think noticing that this is a quadratic equation in $y=x^4$ might help

Comment: Use pari for computing the diescriminant for t up to 40, search for a pattern, then prove it.